# Unity IBM Watson Translation, using the example scene with correct credentials does not work but also shows no error message

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, machine-translation

i am using the IBM Watson SDK for Unity (2019.2.11f1) to st up a simple tranlsation scene. First i tried the example code from the ibm watson live translation where the translation scene is already there. Basically you only have to add the IAMKey and the URL which i did. When i startt (play) the scene nothing happens. I dont get any error messege which shows me that the key and url are correct but still nothing happen.

Does anyone face simliar problems and has any idea what im doing wrong or if i am missing something?

One of the scripts that im tried is:

```
namespace LangaugeTranslatorDemo
{
    public class LanguageTranslatorSample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region PLEASE SET THESE VARIABLES IN THE INSPECTOR
        [Space(10)]
        [Tooltip("The service URL (optional). This defaults to \"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/langauge-translator/api\"")]
        [SerializeField]
        private string serviceUrl;
        [Tooltip("Text field to display the results of translation.")]
        public Text ResultsField;
        [Header("IAM Authentication")]
        [Tooltip("The IAM apikey.")]
        [SerializeField]
        private string iamApikey;
        [Header("Parameters")]
        // https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator#list-models
        [Tooltip("The translation model to use. See https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator#list-models.")]
        [SerializeField]
        private string translationModel;
        #endregion

        private LanguageTranslatorService languageTranslator;

        void Start()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(iamApikey))
                throw new IBMException("Please set the Language Translator iamApikey in the inspector.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(translationModel))
                throw new IBMException("Please set the translationModel in the inspector.");
            //  Start coroutine to create service
            StartCoroutine(CreateService());
        }

        private IEnumerator CreateService()
        {
            //  Create authenticator
            Authenticator languageTranslatorAuthenticator = new IamAuthenticator(
                apikey: iamApikey,
                url: serviceUrl
                );

            //  Yield here until we have IAM token data
            while (!languageTranslatorAuthenticator.CanAuthenticate())
                yield return null;

            //  Instantiate service
            languageTranslator = new LanguageTranslatorService(
                versionDate: "2019-09-16", 
                authenticator: languageTranslatorAuthenticator
                );
        }

        //  Call this method from ExampleStreaming
        public void Translate(string text)
        {
            //  Array of text to translate
            List<string> translateText = new List<string>();
            translateText.Add(text);

            //  Call to the service
            languageTranslator.Translate(OnTranslate, translateText, translationModel);
            Translate("Hello");
        }

        //  OnTranslate handler
        private void OnTranslate(DetailedResponse<TranslationResult> response, IBMError error)
        {
            //  Populate text field with TranslationOutput
            ResultsField.text = response.Result.Translations[0]._Translation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Providing your code snippet in your post helps to get your question answered more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need apikey and service url for both Speech to Text and Language Translator. You can add the credentials in the SpeechToTextSample and LangaugeTranslatorSample in the inspector.

[image]